# AsyncStorage not work in header if removeItem in other components

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have home.js and header.js in React.

When using this code, Information will not be erased until the simulator is refreshed
I want to clear the home page async data that state updated when navigate to home but when go to home AsyncStorage have the value
 :

```
 AsyncStorage.removeItem('mobileNumber');
   this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
```

Can anyone please assist me to correct this code?

Comment: removeItem is async, make sure first the item removal is done through callback as the 2nd arg to the removeItem fn, or .then syntax

AsyncStorage.removeItem('mobileNumber', (error) => { if (!error) // exec next op.... })

Comment: thank you,i do it but not working

Comment: Your question as it is written is very broad and unclear. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that those attempting to answer your question are better placed to help.